# Escape Backslash for cmd with C#

Tags: c#, cmd

I have a problem, I'm using a FileBrowserDialog for getting some folders route.
But this gives me routes like this: D:\\Angel\\Desktop\\DWServicio

My problem is: 
I must run windows commands from my application, for example I must run this:
dir D:\Angel\Desktop\DWServicio / b / s > .\archivo.txt

But when I use FileBrowserDialog my code line is: dir D:\\Angel\\Desktop\\DWServicio / b / s > .\archivo.txt

So, I just need escape \\ and get \

In my code:
I'm trying to escape using replace like:

```
exe.ExecuteCommandSync(command.Replace(@"\\", @"\"));
```

or:

```
exe.ExecuteCommandSync(command.Replace("\\", @"\"));
```

etc.

But when I'm debuging result is the same: D:\\Angel\\Desktop\\DWServicio

If I execute this:

```
command = @"dir D:\Digital_Solutions / b / s > d:\archivo.txt";
exe.ExecuteCommandSync(command);
```

Works perfectly, my problem is when I try to use FileBrowserDialog path

Maybe Anyone can help me please? 
thanks in advance.

grettings

Comment: You're right with your first attempt, `exe.ExecuteCommandSync(command.Replace(@"\\", @"\"));`. That'll convert "D:\\" to "D:\"

Comment: You can add a single backslash inside a string by either using a double backslash: `"d:\\"` or by using a verbatim string literal (the `@` character in front of the quotes: `@"d:\"`.

Comment: I think you may be confused. "\\" and @"\" are the same so your command.Replace("\\",@"\") makes no sense. "D:\\" is fine in watch window, it means it has just one `\\`

Comment: Can you please update your question with a reproducible problem, so we know what the issue is? If you're just looking at the string in the debugger, it will have the escape characters in it, but they will not be present in the actual string that's passed to your method (i.e. if you write it to a file, the escape characters will not be there)

Comment: @RufusL I think he sees "\\" in the watch window and believes he has to sanitize the string.

Comment: `FIleBrowserDialog` will return a path that will work for you. It doesn't double backslash; that's just the way strings show up in the debugger.

Comment: Replacing of "\\" with "\" is not necessary. "\\" means "\" is escaped. Try doing a "Console.WriteLine(command)". You will understand what is happening there.

Comment: My problem is: I must run windows commands from my application, for example I must run this: dir D:\Angel\Desktop\DWServicio / b / s > .\archivo.txt

But when I use FileBrowserDialog my code line is: dir D:\\Angel\\Desktop\\DWServicio / b / s > .\archivo.txt


        I just need send the correct lines for windows command

Comment: What makes you think that's your code line? `FileBrowserDialog` does not return a string like that. As several people have mentioned, if you're seeing that in the debugger, it's an artifact of the debugger. Not what the string actually contains.

Comment: If I execute this:

    command = @"dir D:\Digital_Solutions / b / s > d:\archivo.txt";
    exe.ExecuteCommandSync(command);
Works perfectly, my problem is when I try to use FileBrowserDialog path

Comment: You're right Kosala W and  itsme86, it was  an artifact of the debugger. But changing the line, now this is my line: command = "dir " + sSelectedPath + @" / b / s > .\archivo.txt";

Comment: `/ b / s` should be `/b /s`.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using /'s instead?

A quick try of this code:

```
string str = "D:\\Angel\\Desktop\\DWServicio";
Console.WriteLine(str.Replace("\\","/"));
```

Returns D:/Angel/Desktop/DWServicio

Which depending on your needs could work.

Comment: this isn't an answer; it should be in the comments

Comment: Hi Holly,
We must run windows commands, and for example if we must locate one file or folder this is using \ in cmd

Comment: I tried this code:str.Replace("\\","\\") and got D:\Angel\Desktop\DWServicio.. which makes no sense I know. but worth a try.

Comment: A path starting with `"D:"` is unlikely to be a unix/linux system so your answer makes no sense because `/`.is not a valid windows directory separator.

Comment: Hi brad... The path can be any, because I'm opening with FileBrowserDialog, (D:\Angel\Desktop\DWServicio / b / s > .\archivo.txt) is just an example. What I want is get that string without double back slash, I just need one.

Comment: In C# I use '/' all the time, as the '\' char is for escaping out characters and this is why she is getting "D:\\filedirectory\\" instead of "D;\filedirectory\' A common solution is to replace "\' with '/' and in some scenarios this does work. It may not work here as she is using c# to interface with cmd.